# Stopped Laravel queue worker

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

Using AWS elasticbeanstalk.
Setting my deploy_config file like below:

```
  08_queue_service_restart:
    command: "systemctl restart laravel_worker"
files: 
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/laravel-logs.conf: 
    content: /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
  /etc/systemd/system/laravel_worker.service:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # Laravel queue worker using systemd
      # ----------------------------------
      #
      # /lib/systemd/system/queue.service
      #
      # run this command to enable service:
      # systemctl enable queue.service

      [Unit]
      Description=Laravel queue worker

      [Service]
      User=nginx
      Group=nginx
      Restart=always
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --tries=3

      [Install]
      WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And it return error like below:

```
Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: laravel_worker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: Unit laravel_worker.service entered failed state.
    Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: laravel_worker.service failed.
    Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: laravel_worker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: Stopped Laravel queue worker.
    Aug 17 04:21:34 ip-blabla systemd: Started Laravel queue worker.
```

It was working with no error for months. But this morning, started to return error like that. And I tried making rebuild, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It might stopped working when server restart. You have to manually run command in project directory via terminal to restart laravel queue worker.
for me this command worked

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

Run this command into laravel-project-root-directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).